# Remove Div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a code for a page:
show a button and embedded youtube video, once the user clicks on it, he goes to a link (not youtube) and the video disappears.
also there is a button to remove the video.
I've managed to make the video clickable to a link, but the problem that the video doesn't get removed - not when clicked on and not when clicking on the button.

```css
.the-click {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.myxButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px -1px #cf866c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px -1px #cf866c;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px -1px #cf866c;
  background-color: #d0451b;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #942911;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #854629;
}
.myxButton:hover {
  background-color: #bc3315;
}
.myxButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <button class="myxButton" onclick=$( '#div1').remove();>« Stop Video »</button>
  <div id="div1" align="center" class="container" onclick=$( '#div1').remove();>
    <a href="http://www.google.com " class="the-click" target="_blank"></a>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UKftOH54iNU?modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;fs=0&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;disablekb=1&amp;wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</center>
```

[Console result when clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E13tV.png)

**I've also tried:**

```
onclick="$('#div1').remove();"
onclick='$('#div1').remove();'
#same with# onclick=$('#div1').hide();
```

Thanks

Comment: `onclick` attribute without quotes will confuse the browser and you probably want more something like this `$('.myxButton').on('click', function() { $(this).remove(); }` to run when the document is ready. Using `onclick` attribute for JS is not really recommended nowadays.

Comment: Use `onclick="$('#div1').remove();"` note the quotes.. Also I would suggest using Jquery `.on` to bind events rather than inline image HTML

Comment: it works from what i am seeing

Comment: Rajshekar Reddy - I've tried it in many ways (with "",'', without), didn't help :(

GillesC - Thanks, I'm a beginner, how should I implement what you suggested.

Comment: What happens if you do a `console.log('test');` in `onclick` instead of `$('#div1').remove();` ? Do you get the message in the console?

Comment: @Ionut "test" - Video Code.htm:38

Comment: @RajshekarReddy - I've tried it in many ways (with "",'', without), didn't help :(

Comment: @GillesC - Thanks, I'm a beginner, how should I implement what you suggested.

Comment: @Fadi gave you my answer

Comment: You actually have two `onclick`s that are missing their quotes. If you tried adding quotes and still got `Unexpected symbol $`, then you probably did not add quotes to both of them. You should also `return false;` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax. remove your inline `onClick` attribute from the button and use jquery to add the event listener.

Your button HTML should be just

```
 <button class="myxButton">« Stop Video »</button>
```

The reason for asking to remove the inline attribute is because its deprecated already (but still few browsers support it), But in future almost all browsers will stop supporting it. Also this way we keep the HTML and JavaScript code separate which is good for maintenance.

Here is a working snippet.

```js
$('.myxButton').on('click',function(){
  $('#div1').remove();
});
```

```css
.the-click {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.myxButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px -1px #cf866c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px -1px #cf866c;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px -1px #cf866c;
  background-color: #d0451b;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #942911;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #854629;
}
.myxButton:hover {
  background-color: #bc3315;
}
.myxButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center>
  <button class="myxButton">« Stop Video »</button>
  <div id="div1" align="center" class="container">
    <a href="http://www.google.com " class="the-click" target="_blank"></a>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UKftOH54iNU?modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;fs=0&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;disablekb=1&amp;wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Your code still has the inline `onclick` and you use `.on('click')` in jQuery, shouldn't be both ways. This is not a good way to do it.

Comment: @lonut lol I overlooked that one.. I just removed the one in Button.. thanks for pointing it out.